# No Such Method Exception in Guava Set

Tags: nosuchmethoderror, static-functions, static-import, guava

I am getting the following exception while static method of Sets of guava collection is being used, though the method is statically imported. What could be the reason? Guava version used here is `12.0.1`.

```
Exception in thread "Task-Thread-for com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@57e5a02" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets.newLinkedHashSetWithExpectedSize(I)Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;
at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:1034)
at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:445)
at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:183)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:256)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:248)
at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:246)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:960)
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$9.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1519)
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$9.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1489)
at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:77)
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1489)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:162)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:129)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:133)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:120)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:143)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:132)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner$TaskThread.run(ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner.java:255)
```

Comment: Any chance you picked up "Google Collections" rather than Guava? Or maybe you have both, and you're in classpath hell, right now.

Comment: No, actually. I could see the function in the added dependencies, but while executing it's not finding it.

Comment: Could you verify that that's only one `com.google.common.collect.Sets` on the classpath?

Comment: Though different versions of guava are used in parallel projects (with same parent pom), but in this sub-module only one version is used and that contains this particular function.

Comment: I'm not a Maven expert, but I don't think it actually isolates library versions at a classlaoder level.